# im using ag grid react and have applied global font to entire application with that the check box inside the ag grid is losing border and check

Tags: css, ag-grid

[image]
[image]

whole application font is changing but im unable to click on the checkbox and border is also missing but before it was like below

[image]

tried implementing  but not worked

```
*:not(.div):not(.YourClassName){
  font-family:'Roboto-Regular';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Issue is not only css but logic of the grid most probably, it would really help if you could add more information about the grid version, your code and a little bit more information about your problem?